# Can't connect to mongodb from mocha test

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

Connecting from the REPL works fine:

```
> var mongoose=require('mongoose');
undefined
> mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(error) {
... console.log( 'connected\n%s\n', error );
... });
```

returns:

```
{ connections: 
   [ { base: [Circular],
       collections: {},
       models: {},
       replica: false,
       hosts: null,
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 27017,
       user: undefined,
       pass: undefined,
       name: 'test',
       options: [Object],
       _readyState: 2,
       _closeCalled: false,
       _hasOpened: false,
       _listening: false,
       _events: {},
       db: [Object] } ],
  plugins: [],
  models: {},
  modelSchemas: {},
  options: {} }
> connected # Yes!
undefined
```

But connecting from a Mocha test suite does not work:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
console.log( 'connecting...' );

mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/test', function( error ) {
    if( error) console.error( 'Error while connecting:\n%\n', error );

    console.log( 'connected' );
});
```

returns:

```
$ mocha
connecting...



  0 passing (0 ms)
```

Does anyone know why this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any tests in your suite? If not it seems like mocha exits before mongoose gets a chance to connect. One of the features listed on the mocha page is

> auto-exit to prevent "hanging" with an active loop

which may have something to do with it. You could try connecting to mongoose in the before method of your test suite e.g.

```
describe('test suite', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(error) {
            if (error) console.error('Error while connecting:\n%\n', error);
            console.log('connected');
            done(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: when i rund this code i get `Typeerror: done is not a function`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294310/mocha-mongoose-done-is-not-a-function-wdio-mocha-framework

Comment: Place the done(); outside of the mongoose.connect function it will have access to the done method.